# Laravel - link paypal payment to order id

Tags: laravel, paypal, relationship

I'm using this to handle paypal payments: https://artisansweb.net/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-laravel/

My paments page has this URL: `/shop/order/1/payment`
Where `1` is the ID of the order.

Once the payment comes back, the 'payment_success' method saves the payment information to the database, but I do not have any connection the the ID above.. So I do not know what order has been paid..

How can I pass on this information, so that in the end when I process the received order I know what the user has paid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're saving the payment_id to your order row you could simply find the order by doing

`Order::query()->where('payment_id', $request->input('paymentId'))->first()`

If it exists, this will get you the order you need.

Comment: I cannot save the payment id, since the payment id is only given when the payment is done.. and when I have the payment ID i have already lost the Order Id..